# java cumulative kernel density estimation

Tags: java, statistics, weka

I have some log likelihood scores from an unknown distribution and I want to approximate the cumulative density function (i.e calculate p(x < Y) for a given Y). I am using java.

I tried using weka's KernelEstimator but its getProbability method returns strange values, I think it is the local probability and not the CDF. Is there any way to get the CDF from a kernel estimator in weka? Is there another java package I should consider for this?

Thanks.